# Django Model designing with M2M

Tags: django, django-models

I need some help regarding models designing.

I have two models like this (with M2M Field)

```
class Control(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default=NOT_PLANNED,
                              blank=True,
                              null=True)
                              
class Vulnerability(models.Model):

    id = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    controls = models.ManyToManyField("Control",
                                      verbose_name="control",)
```

What I want to do :
When I create a vulnerability with several controls, each control have a weight for the vulnerability.
So I can't create a weight field in my control, since it'll be a weight for each vulnerability.

The only thing I found is to create a new "linking" class :

```
class VulnerabilityControl(models.Model)
    vulnerability = models.ForeignKey(....)
    control = models.ForeignKey(...)
    weight = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

But it create a new table etc.. Is there a better way to do this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Birmsi's answer - you are on the right track.

The only thing I would add is that, with your method, there are now two tables that track the M2M relationships between Controls and Vulnerabilities.

To specify that Django should use your VulnirabilityControl model as the singular table that manages these M2M relationships you can add the `through` parameter to the M2M field declaration like so:

```
class Vulnerability(models.Model):

    ...

    # add the through parameter to the M2M field:
    controls = models.ManyToManyField( ... , through='VulnaribilityControl')
```

Comment: I don't get the utility of "through"... Because it's working without. Why are you telling me without "through" there are 2 tables ? For me, there is one for control, one for vulnerability and one for vulnerabilitycontrol ?

Comment: @ExploiterZ if you do not specify the through parameter, you will have two tables managing the M2M relation: the one you have created (by declaring the class `VulnerabilityControl` ) and the one that django has created automatically (by declaring the ManyToManyField). [Please read the docs on that topic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)

Answer (score 1):

Django creates a "through" model in order to "track" the relationship between your model.
Take a look at their [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields).

In that example the Membership will hold the relationship (Foreign Key) between the Person and Group models.

I wouldn't mind having another table on the db, it might even be better.
That way you can see/ control your data in the db layer and not just saved in some way on the application.
Have had some times that it was easier to fix a mistake in a many to many relationship by just going to the intermediate table and changing the value.